# CKEditor - how to show current color *on* text color button?

Tags: ckeditor

Does CK Editor have the ability to show the current color *on* the Text Color *button*?

(The text edit area works fine/no problem - wondering specifically if the *button itself* can change to reflect the current color.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No, CKEditor doesn't provide this feature.

Long ago I provided a patch to implement it, but currently that's totally outdated and it would need to be rewritten from scratch.